# How to use VIM to remember open files between sessions?

Tags: file, unix, vim

I use VIM as my main text editor here at work and I often have 10-15 files open at once in a couple of Windows with several tabs, each of which has its own split Windows. I love using VIM, but I hate having to re-do my entire set-up every time the dev server gets bounced or my machine crashes.

Is there a way to get VIM to remember a setup, such as the "project" features in many IDEs? Or am I stuck having to open all the files in the same way each time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [`:mksession`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#views-sessions) command.

> A Session keeps the Views for all windows, plus the global settings.  You can
>   save a Session and when you restore it later the window layout looks the same.
>   You can use a Session to quickly switch between different projects,
>   automatically loading the files you were last working on in that project.

Answer (score 7):

Check help for **mksession**